# Uncaught ReferenceError: function Post() is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use JS and Jquery functions:

```
//Jquery
$(function(){

  function Post(id) {
    $.post('index.php', {
            id: id
            },function (data) {alert(data) });
}  
});

//Javascript

Func.addCallback('onSuccess', function(id) {

 Post(id);
}
```

I get error when use code:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: wallPost is not defined
```

I  know that error becose function javascript use function jQuery, but how remove error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should defined the `Post` function outside of the `$(document).ready` callback or it won't be visible to the outside:

```
function Post(id) {
    $.post('index.php', { id: id }, function (data) {alert(data) });
}

//Jquery
$(function() {
    // this will execute when the DOM is ready
});

//Javascript
Func.addCallback('onSuccess', function(id) {
    Post(id);
}
```

If on the other hand you are attempting to use jQuery with other js frameworks that might be hijacking the `$` function you may take a look at the corresponding section in the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Answer (score 1):

`Post` is only defined within the context of `document.ready()`. Once you leave the document ready method, that function is no longer available.  If you need to use it elsewhere, define it outside of the `document.ready()` function.